# how to convert newline-delimitted semi-structured data to structured

Tags: python, bash, text

I have a [data set](http://www.memetracker.org/data.html) where each record is delimitted by an empty line:

```
P http://codeproject.com/kb/silverlight/convertsilverlightcontrol.aspx
T 2008-08-01 00:00:00
Q how to create property binding in a visual webgui silverlight control
Q videoplayer silverlight controls videoplayer videoplayer silverlight controls version 1 0 0 0 culture neutral publickeytoken null
Q videoplayer controls videoplayer videoplayer controls

P http://wallstreetexaminer.com/?p=2987
T 2008-08-01 00:00:01

P http://news.bbc.co.uk/go/rss/-/1/hi/scotland/highlands_and_islands/7535558.stm
T 2008-08-01 00:00:01
Q our continuing strategic priority is to provide a safe and efficient group of airports while pursuing development opportunities which improve the air transport network serving the region
Q our results for the year demonstrate that we have delivered against these targets and ensured that our airports have continued to play a central role in the economic and social life of the highlands and islands and tayside

P http://news.bbc.co.uk/go/rss/-/1/hi/scotland/south_of_scotland/7535392.stm
T 2008-08-01 00:00:01
Q safeguard our fishing communities birthright for future generations
Q every time i visit a fishing community in scotland i am asked to take steps to protect fishing rights for future generations

P http://news.bbc.co.uk/go/rss/-/1/hi/scotland/north_east/7535090.stm
```

every line is considered a separate "field". certain fields appear multiple times for the same record. here is the data "schema". as you can see the phrase or "Q" can appear multiple times for the same record.

where the first letter of the line encodes:

- `P`: URL of the document
- `T`: time of the post (timestamp)
- `Q`: phrase extracted from the text of the document
- `L`: hyper-links in the document (links pointing out to other documents on the web)

How do I convert this dataset into a form which I can more easily run aggregations, groupings, counts, distincts, statistics?

Ideally, it would be most helpful to convert this dataset into csv or json format so that I can use already-built tools such as bash/python/R/mongodb in order to do text mining / processing / natural language processing.

Comment: They _document the format for you_. Read it line by line, and covert to JSON by group (breaking at the empty line). You have a bigger issue, though, in that these files tend to be 4G+. R has memory limits (and despite what Python ppl say, it does too). I'm not sure what ML/NLP tools you'll use in `bash`. You're going to really need to consider your analysis pipeline/architecture to do what you desire and it seems you're stuck at "basic text file parsing".

Comment: @hrbrmstr i appreciate the response. what do you recommend to use for converting to json? what architecture would you recommend, where i dont have to outsource to AWS, to process a large dataset?

Comment: R or Python (or Perl or node or anything) can do this conversion _really_ easily. SO is not a coding service, though, so unless you post code of what you try and did not succeed with, there's not much more than that. I'd look into Spark for doing this at-scale analysis (and it has interfaces to R & Python).

Comment: Lack of effort, I assume. This is straightforward to solve in any programming language.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Following code takes a file in a given format and produces csv. Multiple appearances of same phrase are joined with pipe.

```
#!/usr/bin/perl -wl


my @t = qw(P T Q L);
my %h = ();

while (<>) {


    if (/^$/ .. /^$/) {

        my $r = "";

        foreach my $k (@t) {

            $r .= ',' if length($r) > 0;
            $r .= join('|', @{$h{$k}}) if exists($h{$k});           
        }

        print $r;
        %h = ();

    } else {

        if (/^([PTQL])\s+(.*)$/) {

            $h{$1} = () unless exists($h{$1});  
            push @{$h{$1}}, $2;
        }
    }
}
```

Obviously, not a Python solution and a bit naive approach since there's no escaping of used separators (comma and pipe) within a field.